# ¿Como actualizar el objeto nativo de usuarios de Firebase con Angular2?

Tags: firebase, angularjs-2.0

He estado implementando un sistema de roles mientras trabajo con firebase y AngularFire2. Al final pude lograrlo. Lo pude hacer con colecciones paralelas en la realTime database, pero me quedaron dudas.

Me gustaría saber si es posible (y de ser así, como se haría) para actualizar directamente un usuario creado por el sistema de autenticación de Firebase.

Digamos que creo un usuario programáticamente:

```
this.af.auth.createUser({ 'email': email, 'password': password })
    .then(createdUser => {
        ...
        createdUser['role'] = foo;
        ...... // Como puedo decirle a Firebase que actualice el usuario recién creado al nuevo objeto?
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Es mas algo teórico la verdad, pero me gustaría saber si esto se puede hacer, ya sea con AngularFire2 o directamente con la API nativa de Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, puedes actualizarlo el usuario con estos dos metodos de FireBase no AngularFire2: 
(userdata.value tiene las propiedades photoURL y displayName)

```
changeUser(userData) {
 if(userData.valid) {
  console.log(userData.value);
  this.auth.currentUser.updateProfile(userData.value)
    .then((success) => {
      console.log('Success', success);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
 }
}
changeEmail(emailData) {
 if(emailData.valid) {
  console.log(emailData.value);
  this.auth.currentUser.updateEmail(emailData.value.email)
    .then((_) => {
      console.log('Success');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
 }
}
```

Pero si lo que quieres es asignar roles de usuario estos sistemas no lo soportan directamente.